# Load a file in ocaml recursive way

Tags: file, recursion, load, ocaml

Basically i have a list of caches and a cache is a user-defined type with 16 parameters. With my code im only reading from an existing file the first cache that exists, how do i recursively read all the caches in the file?

The cache is already ready to be read:

```
let loadCache ci =
    let code = input_line ci in
    let name = input_line ci in
    let state = input_line ci in
    let owner = input_line ci in
    let latitude = float_of_string (input_line ci) in
    let longitude = float_of_string (input_line ci) in
    let kind = input_line ci in
    let size = input_line ci in
    let difficulty = float_of_string (input_line ci) in
    let terrain = float_of_string (input_line ci) in
    let status = input_line ci in
    let hiddenDate = input_line ci in
    let nFounds = int_of_string (input_line ci) in
    let nNotFounds = int_of_string (input_line ci) in
    let nFavourites = int_of_string (input_line ci) in
    let altitude = int_of_string (input_line ci) in {
        code = code; name = name; state = state; owner = owner;
        latitude = latitude; longitude = longitude;
        kind = kind; size = size; difficulty = difficulty; terrain = terrain;
        status = status; hiddenDate = hiddenDate;
        nFounds = nFounds; nNotFounds = nNotFounds; nFavourites = nFavourites;
        altitude = altitude
    }
;;
```

And this is what im trying to do to read(not recusive yet):

```
val load: string -> cache list

let rec loadChannel ci =
  try
    loadCache ci
  with End_of_file -> raise (Arg.Bad "loadChannel: no caches on this file to read")     
;;

let load filename = (* post: result is never [] *)
 let ci = open_in filename in
    let cl = loadChannel ci in
      close_in ci; cl
;;
```

And in case you need to test it im putting here the cache type so you don't have to create it:

```
type cache = {          
    code: string;       
    name: string;       
    state: string;      
    owner: string;      
    longitude: float;   
    kind: string;       
    size: string;       
    difficulty: float;  
    terrain: float;     
    status: string;     
    hiddenDate: string; 
    nFounds: int;       
    nNotFounds: int;    
    nFavourites: int;   
    altitude: int       
} ;;
```

One last thing, to test and see if this is working just type the complete path where the file is:

```
let q = load "C: ...... file.txt"
```

Comment: Well, it's always a pleasure to answer and have no feedback ;-)

Answer (score 0):

When you write :

```
let rec loadChannel ci =
  try
    loadCache ci
  with End_of_file -> raise (Arg.Bad "loadChannel: no caches on this file to read")
```

You could instead write :

```
let loadCache ci =
  let code = try Some (input_line ci) with End_of_file -> None in
  match code with 
   | None -> raise Exit
   | Some code ->
     try
       let name = input_line ci in
       let state = input_line ci in
       let owner = input_line ci in
       let latitude = float_of_string (input_line ci) in
       let longitude = float_of_string (input_line ci) in
       let kind = input_line ci in
       let size = input_line ci in
       let difficulty = float_of_string (input_line ci) in
       let terrain = float_of_string (input_line ci) in
       let status = input_line ci in
       let hiddenDate = input_line ci in
       let nFounds = int_of_string (input_line ci) in
       let nNotFounds = int_of_string (input_line ci) in
       let nFavourites = int_of_string (input_line ci) in
       let altitude = int_of_string (input_line ci) in 
       {
          code; name; state; owner; latitude; longitude;
          kind; size; difficulty; terrain; status; hiddenDate;
          nFounds; nNotFounds; nFavourites; altitude
       }
     with End_of_file -> raise (Arg.Bad "loadChannel: no caches on this file to read or not enough informations")

let rec loadChannel ci acc =
  try
    let c = loadCache ci in
    loadChannel ci (c::acc)
  with Exit -> acc (* If we have an Exit, it means that the first read
                      was an End_of_file so it's not a mistake, just
                      a proper End_of_file. If this exception appears
                      after, it means that we were reading a cache and
                      couldn't finish the reading. *)

let load filename = (* post: result is never [] *)
  let ci = open_in filename in
    let cl = loadChannel ci in
    close_in ci; 
    match cl with
      | [] -> raise BIGEXCEPTION
      | _ -> cl
```

And you have a nice list of cache (not empty) ;)

By the way, in a record, lets say

```
 type r = {a : int; b : int}
```

if you write

```
 let a = 3 and b = 4 in {a = a; b = b}
```

since your field name are 'a' and 'b', you can write

```
 let a = 3 and b = 4 in {a; b}
```

and OCaml will fill it properly. ;)